# Rolling Subsetting of Data.table for rolling statistics

Tags: r, data.table

I have a strange problem that I know I can solve with `apply` or some other looping structure but I feel like there should be a really clever way to do this. I have a data.table `example_dt` that I extract 2 id columns from to form a id data.table called `id_dt`.

I then want to use these id's to index into `example_dt` to compute some statistics. The trick is that the first id, `id1`, needs to match. The second id, `id2`, just needs to be within a certain range. I rename the columns in the `id_dt` to avoid naming conflicts. I'm not completely sure what's going on with the scoping in the `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
example_dt <- data.table( id1 = c(rep('a', 7), rep('b', 7)), id2 = c(1:7, 1:7), x1 = c(rep(1:2,7)))
id_dt <- example_dt[,.(id1, id2)]
setnames(id_dt, names(id_dt), c('id1_idx','id2_idx') )
result_dt <- id_dt[,example_dt[id1 == id1_idx & id2 <= id2_idx & id2 >= id2_idx - 2, mean(x1)]]
```

What I'm getting is just a single value of 1.5

```
> result_dt
[1] 1.5
```

What I want is this:

```
id1 id2 x1  mean
a   1   1   1
a   2   2   1.5
a   3   1   1.333333333
a   4   2   1.666666667
a   5   1   1.333333333
a   6   2   1.666666667
a   7   1   1.333333333
b   1   2   2
b   2   1   1.5
b   3   2   1.666666667
b   4   1   1.333333333
b   5   2   1.666666667
b   6   1   1.333333333
b   7   2   1.666666667
```

Like I said, I know I can do it with `apply` or some other looping structure. I'm wanting to see if there is some clever `data.table` incantation I am not aware of.

Comment: What's happening with the mean in your desired result?  Is there a grouping variable or is that a rolling mean, etc?  I have fixed your code up to the part that calculates the mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using `rolling joins`:

```
setkey(example_dt, id1, id2)
idx1 = example_dt[.(id1, id2-2), roll=-Inf, which=TRUE]
idx2 = example_dt[.(id1, id2), roll=Inf, which=TRUE]

mapply(function(x,y) mean(example_dt$x1[x:y]), idx1, idx2)
#  [1] 1.000000 1.500000 1.333333 1.666667 1.333333 1.666667 1.333333 2.000000 1.500000
# [10] 1.666667 1.333333 1.666667 1.333333 1.666667
```

It could also be done using `foverlaps()`, but it seems a bit of an overkill. I suggest you've a look at `?data.table` at the `roll` argument and work the examples there if you don't manage to get a hold of this.. (until vignettes for joins are completed). For other vignettes, check the [Getting started](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) page. For vignettes planned, have a look at [this post](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944).

This has come up quite a few times, that it might be worth making `between()` function in `data.table` capable of performing this (efficiently). I think there's an FR somewhere on the project page.

As to why you get a single value, you are doing `DT[rows, mean(col)]`, which reads.. extract `col` for rows specified in `rows`, and compute its mean. And that should return a single value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm wrestling through exactly what the syntax means. I'm used to dplyr for this kind of work but it wasn't working for this scenario.